# swift4: use func generic type to specify the generic type of another func

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I want to specify the type for data response in my own function request

```
func request<T>(urlString: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters, headers: HTTPHeaders,
                callBack:@escaping (T) -> Void,
                failureHandler:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
        <#code#>
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the image and post the code here please.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

```
func request<T: BaseMappable>(urlString: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters, headers: HTTPHeaders,
                callBack:@escaping (T) -> Void,
                failureHandler:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let result):
            callBack(result)
        case .failure(let error):
            failureHandler(error)
        }
    }
}
```